# Accessing infinispan cache across diffrent network

Tags: java, azure, infinispan

Here we have situation in which we have one service which needs to be run in cluster mode for which we preferred infinispan for detection of services running on different machines and have data in concurrent mode.

1) Now, when we run our service in our LAN all works fine. When first service starts it creates its own cluster and it is treated as master. when second service starts it finds this already created cluster and joins it and treat itself as slave.

2) Now problem is that for load balancing we use Azure VM instances which are out of the network nodes and so they do not find this already created cluster and creates their own cluster outside.

3) Now I want to know that how service running on this cloud VM will find my already create cloud in my network and will join it as slave.

I know that we will require an external IP address but how to do this all infinispan configuration for making connection from services running outside network?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a [cross-site replication](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Cross+site+replication) to get that kind of architecture working as expected. The idea is that each network forms its own cluster and then these are linked via a relay.